# What kind of emulator can i use to learn Cisco Router Configuration?

Tags: networking, cisco, router

I am going through my CCNA materials. I came across this one topic called configuring the router. Now, i don't have a Cisco Router but i still want to go through the commands and see the results live. I can't manage a router as of now, so is there some sort of emulator that i can use to virtually configure the router and go through my lab exercises. Please help me out as my CCNA exam is approaching close.

Answer (score 1):

There's many... you didn't specify much so i'll give my recommendation.

I love GNS3:
https://www.gns3.com/ Works best in linux.

Then you can see:

http://www.unetlab.com/

http://virl.cisco.com/

I have not tested the ones below.